# Why does Perl short circuit evaluation result in checking rvalue?

Tags: perl

I don't understand why the following:

```
my $err = undef;

while(1){
  if($err && ($err->code == 502)) {
    [...]
  }
  [...]
  eval {...}
  $err = $@;
}
```

results in `Can't call method "code" on an undefined value at ./filename.pl line 74.` in perl v5.8.8.
In other words: why does perl execute the second boolean expresion, even if the `OP1 && OP2` construct **cannot** become true because the first operand is false (undef).

even the more verbose version `if( (defined $err) && ($err->code == 502))` produces the same result.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can't reproduce that (on 5.10, admittedly). Can you give a small-but-complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: My comment includes a complete Perl script.  I don't know how to do that readably here in this comment column, so let me post it as an answer, below.

Comment: sorry, but the program uses Net::Twitter (quite many deos) and when using a reduced code fragment, it indeed does the right thing... please be patient, I'll try to find a sample

Answer (score 1):

For information, when I run your code as follows on a Perl 5.10.1 interpreter, I get no error message at all.  (This is really more a comment than an answer, only it does not fit in the comment column.  It needs no upvote.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use integer;

my $err = undef;

while(1){
  if($err && ($err->code == 502)) {
    warn;
  }
  eval {1};
  $err = $@;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is undef as you say, that version of Perl or your build of `perl` is buggy if you get that behaviour from that code. Neither is likely.

But it might not be undef. Keep in mind that the error might not come from the first pass of the loop. `$err` might contain an object with buggy overloaded operators (e.g. inconsistent boolean and stringification overloads). What does the following show?

```
use Devel::Peek;
Dump($err);
```

Comment: It's really strange, if I execute only the relevant fragment, the behaviour is as expected, once I run the whole script, which is too long to post, the error occurs... I'm currently building a 5.14, let's see if that helps

Comment: the line shows: `SV = NULL(0x0) at 0xec61670
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADBUSY,PADMY)
`

Comment: I think the more likely answer is that the original post just isn't right.

Comment: @brian d foy, You did not read correctly. I said it's a bug in Perl **if that code gave the stated behaviour**. Your "correction" doesn't make sense under that condition.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why $err ($@)  was obviously not `undef` after the `eval{}` was that a spawned function within the `eval` returned an error beacause of its disability to read from a file which wasn't caught by the sourrounding code :(

Thanks @ikegami for the suggestion, I got the trace using Dump after all.

The solution for the problem therefore is outside of the democode, sorry for that. I just had to create the file...